# Jquery Lightbox Breaks when another script is used delegate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, lightbox, live

Its probably a lot easier if I send the URL

http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~staged2b/about/staff

Everything works with the light box script until the filter between categories is used.

(click Design radio then click thumbnail and lightbox does not work)

I believe i need to use .delegate or .live on the lightbox script but I can seem to get it to work.

Can anyone help that would be great :),

Thanks
Brent

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $("#various1").fancybox({
            'width'             : '47%',
            'height'            : '50%',    
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'
        });
```

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` on `staff: row 513` try to remove `(jQuery)`

Comment: Where do you want me to remove jQuery from?

Comment: I tried remove Jquery and it did not work, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put all your script into the same "anonymous" function (`$(function() { });`) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

 ...

// DOMContentLoaded
$(function() {

  // bind radiobuttons in the form
  var $filterType = $('#filter input[name="type"]');
  var $filterSort = $('#filter input[name="sort"]');

  // get the first collection
  var $applications = $('#applications');

  // clone applications to get a second collection
  var $data = $applications.clone();

  // attempt to call Quicksand on every form change
  $filterType.add($filterSort).change(function(e) {
    if ($($filterType+':checked').val() == 'all') {
      var $filteredData = $data.find('li');
    } else {
      var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type=' + $($filterType+":checked").val() + ']');
    }

    // if sorted by size
    if ($('#filter input[name="sort"]:checked').val() == "size") {
      var $sortedData = $filteredData.sorted({
        by: function(v) {
          return parseFloat($(v).find('span[data-type=size]').text());
        }
      });
    } else {
      // if sorted by name
      var $sortedData = $filteredData.sorted({
        by: function(v) {
          return $(v).find('strong').text().toLowerCase();
        }
      });
    }   

    // finally, call quicksand
    $applications.quicksand($sortedData, {
      duration: 800,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });

  });
// >>>>>>>>>>>>> TO HERE >>>>>>>>>>>>>
// >>>>>>>>>>>>> TO HERE >>>>>>>>>>>>>
});

    // ----- remove this ---->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 


$(function() {
    // <---- remove this -----
// <<<<<<<<<<<< MOVE THIS <<<<<<<<<<<<
    $(".imgHover")
        .live('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".hover").show();
        })
        .live('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").hide();
        });
// <<<<<<<<<<<< MOVE THIS <<<<<<<<<<<<
    // ----- remove this ---->
})(jQuery);
    // <---- remove this -----

</script>
```

Comment: Hi ClydeFrog thanks for the reply I really appreciate it, i tried what you said and it didn't work? Any other ideas mate, been pulling my hair out for last 8 hours! :( Thanks

Comment: Have you done the editings that Clyde mentioned in the script?

Comment: Yeah and it still works but when you choose a radio button (design) etc, the lightbox stops working to click into staff profiles.

Comment: Would'nt the lightbox script have to be .live or delagate?

Comment: alright, at least you're not getting any JS-error anymore! :) some good news. Now i get: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~staged2b/css/template.css` ... maybe there's a css error?

Comment: or maybe the dot isn't supposed to be there when you're editing css-classes with jQuery `$(".imgHover")` -> `$("imgHover")` ?

Comment: Thanks, as i'm working in joomla I have a local style sheet I look at when editing the templates. I tried removing the . and it broke the pop out boxes. Any other ideas why this is not working?

Comment: ClydeFrog if you want I can send you 10$-20$ in paypal if you can work out a solution,thanks

Comment: Not trying to be disrespectful but keep your money, dude. I'm not charging people on this forum :P. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FS9t2/) of your page and I'm trying to make some adjustments. Give me some time to work on it

Comment: Hi Brent! sorry for not answering you sooner. [Made some adjustments where I moved all your javascript and css settings inside the header, formatted the page and removed all the `$("#various1").fancybox(` script which didn't do nothing except taking a lot of space](http://jsfiddle.net/FS9t2/5/). I think I'm able to run the page as you want it in Chrome and Firefox. The thumbs and the filter doesn't work in IE 8 when I run the page I'm afraid :S

Comment: Hi Cylde, no problem thanks for help; It seems to not be working on your page, the lightbox opens in a new window not a frame.

Comment: I ended up using another lightbox script and it worked thanks for help :)